# Equivalentes a "Controladores" en .Net Framework

Tags: .net

Hace unos meses tuve un error y cree lo que debería ser una página web en ASP.Net Core como una biblioteca de clases. Por varias cosas que se utilizan y por incompatibilidad, tengo que pasarla a .Net Framework (4.6.1 específicamente).

Soy consciente de que tengo que rehacer casi todo el código pero, dado que soy nueva en este lenguaje/formato, no tengo muy claro dónde debería tratar de rehacer la parte del controlador de ASP.Net Core o como llamarlo. Al crearlo VS lo hace automáticamente en una carpeta llamada "App_Code" pero ¿funciona igual que si fuera un controlador? ¿Puedo *invocarlo* de la misma manera?

Para métodos post, por ejemplo, lo llamo desde JQuery con AJAX de la siguiente manera en ASP.Net Core:

```
$.post({
                    url: '/Home/Login',

...
});
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo usar ese `url: '/Home/Login',` para llamar a la función correspondiente... ¿se puede?

Comment: No se si entiendo muy bien. En asp.net mvc existen controladores, como su propio nombre indica

Comment: No controlo mucho as.net en general, así que pido perdón si es una pregunta estúpida. Cuando creo el controlador en Core, se crea en una carpeta llamada "Controllers". Si la creo con Framework esa carpeta no existe ¿Funciona como un controlador de la misma manera o hay que hacer algo diferente para invocarlo?

Comment: Yo lamentablemente no soy un experto en asp ya que me dedico casi en exclusiva a aplicaciones de escritorio. Lo que te quería decir es que en lugar de crear un proyecto asp.net normal, debes crear un proyecto asp.net MVC, que será mas similar a lo que tenias con core. Alguien que tenga mas experiencia en asp tal vez pueda ayudarte mas

Comment: Intentamos también con MVC pero utilizamos un webservice que, al parecer, sólo es compatible con Framework. Aún así, muchas gracias por intentar ayudar!

Comment: Asp.net mvc es solo una "capa" por asi decirlo encima de asp.net. Todo lo que sea compatible con asp.net debería serlo con mvc (otra cosa es core, que es totalmente diferente). Siento no poder ayudarte mas.

Comment: A que llamas tu controlador? a la API que recibe la llamada?? fijate sobre rutas, ya que no importa la dll que crees se puede poner la ruta que quieras como llamada a ella.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo crear un proyecto MVC dentro de la solución y utilizar las librerias de clase de los otros proyectos, o rehacer todo dentro del proyecto MVC y creando una carpeta para Lógica de Negocios / Acceso a Datos y ahi mover todo tu código.

Es un tema extenso y hay muchas formas de ramificar las carpetas de tu proyecto, pero el hecho es que tienes que crear un proyecto MVC para poder usar Controladores (claro que tu podrías programar tu propia version de controladores o usar una libreria / framework que no sea de microsoft pero no sería lo mas óptimo).

Hechale un ojo a esto.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Te lo advierto, es un tema extenso, no es algo que se pueda responder en una pregunta de Stackoverflow, pero si ya tienes noción sobre el patrón de diseño Modelo Vista Controlador quizas no te de mucha guerra (lo digo porque mencionas Controladores).

Si tienes alguna duda, preguntame y te puedo ayudar por Msg.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Al final encontramos una forma de mantener el proyecto sin tener que rehacerlo con otro tipo. Aún así le echaré un vistazo a lo que has puesto por si acaso, nunca viene mal aprender.